# Compute distance in Cartesian Coordinate System in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, distance, norm, cartesian

Analyzing Eye-movements on a screen, I set my origin to the bottom left corner of it 
(Hard to modify at that point).

Trying to compute distance between some points and the center of the screen I use the simple formula displayed below. 
Problem is that using this in conditional statement, it gets ugly.

```
Sqrt[
(
(fixationX - centerX)^2 + (fixationY - centerY)^2
)
]
```

Is there a way to customize Norm to compute distance between points and not between a point and the origin ?

Or in my case, set the origin to be at the "center" of the current coordinate system ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slight variation of Simon's method is to use a default value in the function, rather than a global variable (`$Center`).

Suppose your default origin is (5, 5), then:

```
myNorm[pos:{_, _}, center_:{5, 5}] := EuclideanDistance[pos, center]
```

Notice the use of `_:{5, 5}` to define the default value.

Now you can do:

```
myNorm[{5, 7}]

(* Out[]= 2 *)
```

Or temporarily use a different the center with:

```
myNorm[{5, 7}, {8, 8}]

(* Out[]= Sqrt[10] *)
```

For this simple function, you could use `EuclideanDistance` in the second case instead, but I hope you can see the utility of this method were the definition of `myNorm` more complex.

The downside to this method is that you cannot easily change the default center.

---

Another variation that does allow one to easily change the default center, but is more verbose, is to use `Options`:

```
Options[myNorm2] = {Center -> {5, 5}};

myNorm2[pos : {_, _}, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 EuclideanDistance[pos, OptionValue[Center]]
```

Syntax is:

```
myNorm2[{5, 7}]

myNorm2[{5, 7}, Center -> {8, 8}]
```

```
   2
```

```
   Sqrt[10]
```

Changing the default center:

```
SetOptions[myNorm2, Center -> {8, 8}];

myNorm2[{5, 7}]
```

```
   Sqrt[10]
```

Comment: @500 you're welcome.  Please see my updated answer for another method.

Comment: I've made exactly the same mistake you had with `Default` in your first version. I was so far along in the project before I noticed that I just put a comment about it at the top which said `"if you change $xyz, you need to redefine the following..."`!

Comment: @Simon if it got both of us, I am going to post a question about this.  The fact that `DefaultValues[f]` changes without effect is confusing.

Comment: Yeah, it might be a "bug". You can see why a `f[a_:$d] := ...` definition would not care about changing `$d`. But just looking at the downvalues of `Default[g]=$d ; g[a_.] := ...` shows no reason why changing either of `Default[g]` or `$d` has no effect.

Answer (score 4):

Can you just use `EuclideanDistance`

```
In[1]:= EuclideanDistance[{x,y}, {cx,cy}]
Out[1]= Sqrt[Abs[-cx +x ]^2 + Abs[-cy + y]^2]
```

Or define a `$Center` and a new `CNorm`, e.g.

```
$Center = {cx, cy};
CNorm[pos:{x_, y_}] := EuclideanDistance[pos, $Center]
```

Comment: Thank You, I posted this before I saw your e-mail,I might wait to implement now that my function works !

Comment: @500, getting email support from Simon too, eh?  I wish I had the kind of support your getting when I was learning Mathematica. :-)

Comment: @Mr Wizard, Seriously, it is amazing, this generosity and expertise fueled me with motivation ! I will send you my notebook soon with the hope you`ll like it !

Comment: @500 Thanks, I am sure I will.  If you saw my answer below already, notice that I just changed it.  I make a mistake, as I have not used `Default` in a while.  I am (re)learning too.